# ToolTip encoding issue

Tags: c#, asp.net, encoding, .net-4.0

```
<asp:HyperLink ID="TestHyperLink" runat="server"></asp:HyperLink>
```

I am having the above hyperlink. I am just setting the text with below code:

```
string textFromUser = "This is test's.";
string encodedText=HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(textFromUser);
TestHyperLink.Text = encodedText;
TestHyperLink.ToolTip = encodedText;
```

The issue is that text of hyperlink is coming correct but tooltip is showing encoded characters.
[image]

How can I make tooltip appear in the same way as text is?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're seeing that problem because the attribute value is being encoded twice.

1. The `'` character is encoded into `&#39;`;
2. The `&` character is encoded into `&amp;`.

Finally the output is sent to the browser as `title="This is test&amp;quot;s."`. Since the attribute value is already being encoded by default, you can safely set the `Tooltip` property to the raw text and encode only the text for the `Text` property.

**Note:** In this case the attribute encoding is performed by default, but `HtmlEncode` in .NET versions before 4.0 did not encode the `'` character. See [HtmlEncode and UrlEncode Now Encode Single Quotation Marks](http://www.asp.net/whitepapers/aspnet4/breaking-changes#0.1__Toc256770143).

**Update**: I did some googling and found out this interesting reference ([Which ASP.NET Controls Automatically Encodes?](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sfaust/archive/2008/09/02/which-asp-net-controls-automatically-encodes.aspx)) that may be outdated but at least for this specific case the documented behavior is the one you got.

Comment: Is there any documention where I can check that the ToolTip is encoded by default. Is this feature specific .NET 4 or more?

Comment: I updated the answer but I'm unable to recall where I read about it.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned the ToolTip property of a ASP.NET control will auto encode the value on output/rendering.

This means it is *safe* to set the tooltip to plain text as the page will sanitize the text on rendering.

```
Label1.ToolTip = "Some encoded text < Tag >"
```

Renders HTML output as:

```
<span title="Some encoded text &lt; Tag >"></span>
```

---

If you need to use text that is already encoded, you can set the title attribute instead:

```
Label1.Attributes("title") = "Some encoded text &lt; Tag &gt;"
```

Renders HTML output as:

```
<span title="Some encoded text &lt; Tag &gt;"></span>
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like tooltips do not need encoding the same way the text does.

Try setting the ToolTip directly with `textFromUser` instead of the `encodedText`.

Comment: What about this "Always sanitize output to the browser." http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127510/do-i-need-to-html-encode-title-attributes-tooltips ?